# React component not updating when render props used

Tags: reactjs, mobx, headless-ui

I have a component that pulls data from a store below.

When I access the render props provided, my component state does not update when the store changes.

[With render props example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/still-browser-r83i0q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

When we don't use the render props it works as expected.

[Without render props example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/withouth-render-props-y4hk9z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

How can I access the render props and have the counter increment correctly as shown in the second example provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function that is called with the render props is not watched by the observer function, so it does not signal that React should perform a re-render. You'll notice if you close the Popover and re-open it, the correct value appears once a re-render is forced. You should be able to fix this by wrapping the inner function in another instance of `observer`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import testStore from "./testStore";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { Popover } from "@headlessui/react";

const InnerComponent = observer(({ open, close }) => (
  <>
    <Popover.Button>Open panel</Popover.Button>
    <Popover.Panel>
      <p>{testStore.counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => testStore.incrementCounter()}>Increment</button>
    </Popover.Panel>
  </>
));

const App = observer(() => {
  console.log(testStore);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Popover>
        <InnerComponent />
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```

Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-wave-9scouk?file=/src/App.js:0-614)